# Why ruby's(ver 1.9) pcap gem, hanging after accessing it?

Tags: ruby, pcap

Using ruby 1.9 and latest `gem install pcap` + fix for compiling (convert `->ptr`/`->len` to `_PTR`/`_LEN`), i found that after doing simple code:

```
require 'pcap'
cap = Pcap::Capture.open_offline('1.dmp')
cap.each { |pkt| p pkt.src; }

exit
```

Pcap gem not leaving block `cap.each`, i.e. output:

```
...
213.248.106.202
192.168.1.50
213.248.106.202
192.168.1.50

^C
^C
^C
^C
^C
```

And process can be killed only by `kill -s KILL <process_id>`.
**Is there any way to fix this?**

*P.S. 1.dmp file generated using `tcpdump -w 1.dmp`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pcap::Capture#each or Pcap::Capture#each_packet takes an optional count argument. If it is -1, it loops until EOF.

You could try passing a number to each and see what happens.

```
cap.each_packet(4) {|pkt|p pkt.src}
```

If that hangs, there might be an issue in the extension code.

Comment: Actually, each_packet (in the latest version at least) doesn't take a number - there's an internal @count variable that's initialized when you create the Pcap object  itself.